# Am I stating the theorem about the dual optimization problem correctly?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

For my thesis, I am using a certain theorem that states the equivalence of the dual optimization problem. My source for this is "Learning with Kernels" by Schoelkopf and Smola. The problem is that the theorem is not explicitly stated, but rather slowly developed starting from Theorem 6.26, on pages 170-171, culminating especially, but not only, in equation 6.64.

**Did I summarize the facts correctly?**

**EDIT**: *I am looking for an answer that describes what exactly is wrong with the current wording, describes how to state the theorem correctly and gives a reference.*

> Consider the optimization problem
>   \begin{equation*} \begin{aligned} &
> \underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^d}{\text{minimize}} & & f(z) \\ &
> \text{subject to} & & c_i(z) \leq 0 \text{ for all } i = 1, \ldots, n
> \end{aligned} \end{equation*}
>   where $f, c_i\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ are convex and differentiable for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$.
>   Define the *Lagrangian* to be
>   \begin{align*} &L(z, \alpha) := f(z) +
> \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i c_i(z) \\ &\text{where } \alpha_i \geq 0 \text{
>  for all } i = 1, \ldots, n.
> \end{align*} Then the the above
>   optimization problem is equivalent to
>   \begin{equation*}
> \begin{aligned} & \underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^d, \alpha \in
>  \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{maximize}} & & L(z, \alpha) \\ & \text{subject to}
>  & & \alpha_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i = 1, \ldots, n \\ & \text{and}
>  & & \partial_z L(z, \alpha) = 0. \end{aligned}
> \end{equation*}
>   Furthermore, if there exists $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that for all $ i = 1, \ldots, n$, $c_i(z) < 0$, then the two optimization problems
>   have a solution.
>
> Additionally, if there is any solution $z^\ast$, $\alpha^\ast$, it
>   will fulfill
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^\ast c_i(z^\ast) = 0
> \end{align*}
>   or, equivalently $\alpha_i^\ast c_i(z^\ast) = 0$ for all
>   $i=1, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Do you know what happens if the original primal problem is unbounded below?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Unfortunately I don't know what you mean. Is the theorem false as stated if $f$ is unbounded below?

Comment: @Vincent clearly yes because then the part "then the two optimization problems have a solution" does not make sense. The rest is all true, so I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @LinAlg I am looking for an answer that describes what exactly is wrong with the current wording (basically what you said in your comment), describes how to state the theorem correctly and gives a reference.

Comment: @Vincent The reference you are using seems to care less about theoretical grounds of optimization. It is more interested in applications (algorithms). For example, $\min x$ subject to $x\le 0$ satisfies all the assumptions of Th. 6.28 (convex+Slater), however, the conclusion is not true ($\bar x$ and $\bar\alpha$ do not exist). I would recommend [another book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf).

Comment: Look at Section 5.5.3 of the suggested book.